# How to work around PHP odbc_execute parameters needing single quotes for datetime conversion?

Tags: php, sql-server

I’m trying to convert some code to use PHP’s odbc_prepare and odbc_execute to insert the data into a SQL Server table using parameters for security but I can't get past errors due to the way PHP handles single quotes in parameters and SQL Server's need for single quotes around text to be cast to datetime.

I have a web form that accepts a datetime from the user amongst other data.
The output from the datetime input box (missdt below) is in the format YY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS (e.g. 2019-10-09T10:14:00)

Here’s my code (shortened for this post, yes I clean up the post data in my real code):

```
$missdt = $_POST["missdt"];  // results in 2019-10-09T10:14:00  stored as datetime in SQL Server
$branch = intval($_POST["branch"]);  // stored as integer in SQL Server
$name = $_POST["name"];              // stored as varchar in SQL Server

$params = array($branch, 
        $missdt,               // results in SQL error “Invalid character value for cast specification”
        $name, );
$sql = "insert into my_table (branch, submitted, miss_date, name) 
            values (?, getdate(), ?, ?) ";

$res = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
$stmt = odbc_execute($res, $params);
```

The problem is that the $missdt parameter results in a SQL error “Invalid character value for cast specification”

I’ve tried the following variations for $missdt in the $params array and received the indicated errors:

"'" .  $missdt . "'",  // (added quotes) PHP error can't open file

"' " . $missdt . " '", // (added quotes and spaces) PHP error can't open file

"'" .  $missdt . "' ", // (space after) SQL error Invalid character value for cast specification

'"' . $missdt . '"',   // (double quotes used with set quoted_identifier off) results in “invalid parameter number” & “odbc_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource”

This variation on the sql query works fine but could be abused:

$sql = "insert into my_table (branch, submitted, miss_date, name)       values (?, getdate(), ‘$missdt’, ?) ";

According to the PHP documentation using single quotes before and after a parameter results in the parameter being treated as a filename and a workaround is to add a space to the beginning or end of the parameter.  You can see from the variations I’ve tried above that doesn’t work in this case.  I think this is because SQL Server needs the quotes in order to cast the character data to datetime.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

I’m using PHP 7.1, SQL Server 2014, and Apache on Windows 2012

Comment: It has been a while since I have used SQL server or ODBC under php.  IIRC, you don't need any quotes as long as the data is in the correct format, but that was with the FreeTDS driver.  Apparently the MS driver has some options like `ReturnDatesAsStrings` that you may want to look into.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-date-and-time-type-as-strings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it wasn't the single quotes causing the problem.  It was the "T" in the date-time input.  If I use str_replace and replace the T with a space, the sql using the parameter without quotes works correctly.

for example:
$missdt = str_replace('T', ' ',$_POST["missdt"] );

then

$sql = "insert into my_table (branch, submitted, miss_date, name) 
                   values (?, getdate(), ?, ?) ";

works just fine.